# Connect Analog Audio Line to analog Amplifier IC

Tags: microcontroller, amplifier, audio, integrated-circuit, inverting-amplifier

I have a SoC that uses an Amplifier IC to Output Audio to a 8Ohm Speaker. I want to take the Audio Signal from the IC and give it on the Audio Line of another Circuit.

I am not sure if my circuit is correct. Maybe someone can have a look and maybe did something similar already.

The Picture is taken from the datasheet and the circuit on the right is mine (don`t pay antention to the values of my circuit, they are not correct right now)
I only need advice on the connection between the amplifier and my circuit.

There has to be a load on the VO+/VO- lines or else the IC does not output any audio... just a square wave.

Thanks

EDIT

I had a lot other stuff to do in the past so I could not work on this project. Here is a new schematic of the current circuit. I have a beautiful differential output on the VO+ and VO- Lines but I do not get any output?!?!

[image]

Please see these oscilloscope pictures, on picture 1 you can see that before a sound is played, that both lines are pulled to 2V, that is also the reason why I removed the -5V voltage inverter because I thought the sound is in the positive range so I don`t need the negative voltage...

A beautifull differtial signal...

[image]

So is it a problem that the VO lines are pulled to 2 Volts or what else is the problem? Why am I not getting any output??

Thanks so much :)

Comment: I prefer a [differential amplifier](http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/opamp/opamp_5.html) with split supply.

Comment: In case of a differential amplifier, should I connect a 8Ohm resistor between the Input Terminals? Is there a diff. amp. you would suggest for this case?

Comment: Yes, you should. Because, the feedback line (look at the leftmost circuit) will be broken and the gain will be extremely high, so the output will be clipped. I cannot suggest any specific product but you can design one by yourself. Just study the topic from the link I gave in my first comment.

Comment: OK, I will give it a try. I have only 5V and GND and no negative supply. I want to minimize the noise to have good audio quality. Would a TLE2426 be sufficient to split the supply or do you recommend a kind of a voltage inverter like the MAX1044/ICL7660?
Thank you for your help

Comment: 7660 would be a cheap and sufficient solution. Recommended. You may need a large cap (1000u or so) for better ripple performance. Note that 7660 has low output current capability.

Comment: @RohatKılıç
Is there a better posibility to get negative 5V? I tried a 7660 and it is not good... I have too high riple and probably draw too much current... What would be a better solution?

Comment: [ADM8828 or ADM8829 from Analog Devices](http://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ADM8828_8829.pdf) is a better alternative to 7660, because it has 25mA output current. If you need more output current then go for ADM8660 but it's more expensive than the other two.